# Lock using update query for concurrent updates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have started exploring the locking concepts in SQL Server and  I am just curious about how the below query works. Primarily this targets SQL server 2016

```
// normal sql update query
UPDATE Employee SET code = '32' WHERE id = 101 and code = null;

// any difference if I mention rowlock explicitly for sql server
UPDATE Employee WITH (ROWLOCK) SET code = '32' WHERE id = 101 and code = null;
```

I have a few questions on these two queries any help is greatly appreciated.

1. If I get two concurrent requests to update the above statement will only one succeed? I am expecting only one should get updated rows count as 1 and another request should get 0 since code got updated before the second query runs or will the second query override? but I guess it should fail in where clause.
2. If it overrides then is there any way to lock it so that only one can succeed
3. Does this query also lock the select operations or no?
4. If the lock is applied for select operations then is it on the whole table or only row or the page

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROWLOCK hints merely set locking granularity.  They do not control whether locking occurs.  There is no way to NOT have updates protected by a lock in SQL server regardless of hints or isolation levels only at most one of the queries will commit with a row count of 1.

Whether SELECTs block depends entirely on isolation level.  Generally any data retrieved from the database should always be regarded as stale since before you even see it and handled accordingly.  However while not scalable SQL server does support heavy handed isolation levels which enforce read guarantees at the expense of extreme scaling limitations.

Updates can certainly be used to synchronize certain operations so only one of them can occur at the same time.  For example by starting with an UPDATE statement within a transaction only one of the programs below can execute at the same time. The other must either wait for the executing programs transaction to complete or if it already completed before it started checks @@ROWCOUNT and bails.

Program A:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE Employee SET code = '32' WHERE id = 101 and code IS NULL

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) bail?
...
Do other program A things here...
...
COMMIT
```

Program B:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE Employee SET code = '32' WHERE id = 101 and code IS NULL

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) bail?
...
Do other program B things here...
...
COMMIT
```

Here only Program A makes it past the UPDATE statement and gets to "Do other program A things" Execution of program B is blocked on the UPDATE statement until program A's transaction completes.  When program A is committed then program B would no longer be blocked and bail upon seeing @@ROWCOUNT = 0... If program A is rolled back then program B gets to execute its "Do other program B things" section.